# Spark not launching on Windows Yarn

Tags: windows, apache-spark, hadoop-yarn

I met the following issue that Spark can not launch on Windows Yarn.

```
15/06/05 06:31:34 ERROR spark.SparkContext: Error initializing SparkContext.org.apache.spark.SparkException: Yarn application has already ended! It might have been killed or unable to launch application master.
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.cluster.YarnClientSchedulerBackend.waitForApplication(YarnClientSchedulerBackend.scala:114)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.cluster.YarnClientSchedulerBackend.start(YarnClientSchedulerBackend.scala:59)
```

And when I drill down to Yarn, and get the error:

```
Error: Could not find or load main class '-Dspark.driver.memory=2G'
```

---

**After investigating this issue, the root cause is:**

- In the YARN command generation part, single quotes (‘) will be
  added surrounding some of the java options.
- But Windows does not like the quotes for these options.

Similar to this issue https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-5754 .

*Anyone know how to escape the logic working on Windows Yarn cluster?*

---

**Spark Submit Command:**

```
%SPARK_HOME%\bin\spark-submit.cmd --jars ... ^
--class ....^
--master yarn-client ^
--driver-memory 10G ^
--executor-memory 20G ^
--executor-cores 6 ^
--num-executors 10 ^
QuasarNRT.jar 10 6
```

---

-Tao

Comment: Please post complete spark-submit command..